# Laravel 5.1-Not displaying the image selected from list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to display the image which is selected from the list below. I am giving the demo code here

**HTML:**

```
<div class="full">
{!! HTML::image('assets/images/men1.jpg', 'a picture', array('class' => 'img-responsive')) !!}
<a href="#" class="details"><i class="pe-7s-search"></i></a>
</div>
<div class="previews">
    <div class="box-content">
        <div>
            {!! HTML::image('assets/images/men1.jpg', 'a picture', array('data-full'=>'assets/images/men1.jpg','class'=>'selected'))!!}
        </div>
        <div>
            {!! HTML::image('assets/images/men2.jpg', 'a picture', array('data-full'=>'assets/images/men2.jpg'))!!}
        </div>                            
       </div>
            <div class="nav">
              <span class="prev"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i></span>
              <span class="next"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></span>
            </div>
</div>
```

I want that when I select the second image the class on 2nd image becomes 'class'=>'selected' like the 1st image and in the first  I want to display the 2nd image. Even clicking on next/previous link, I want to display the selected image.

How can I do that? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 0):

i am not 100% sure but this could work. Please try and post feed back.

```
var $selected = $('.selected'); // To get the selected element
var $container = $('.box-content'); // to get the parent of all div which has the images.
if($container.index($selected) == $container.length) {
    // this means the selected element is the last one.
    $container.find('img').removeClass('selected').first().addClass('selected');
} else {
    $container.find('img').removeClass('selected').next().addClass('selected');
}
```

Comment: is there any demo site whr we can try  out something?